# sql performance detail decision with * or specify field

Tags: sql, tunneling

When i write:

```
if not exists (select * from sys_maxkey)
```

is better,or

```
if not exists (select id from sys_maxkey)
```

is better when the table sys_maxkey variable.

or it has no difference?I have found internet and analyse `exists` and `in` but not pay attention to this special point.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use only `1` like this. This would be the best. As `exists` only checks whether there is any entry in your table.

```
if not exists (select 1 from sys_maxkey)
```

Although if you want to compare between the above two mentioned in your question then

```
if not exists (select id from sys_maxkey)
```

would be better provided that `id` is the **primary key**. You dont have to check all the columns by using `*` just for checking whether there exists a value in your table.

Comment: And if you tell me is it have effect about performance using * ?If the table is very very big?Yes i use the primary key to judge.

Comment: Yes definitely but only if your table is very very big. You definitely dont require to fetch all the column just for checking whether the table has an entry or not ;)

Comment: **Yes i use the primary key to judge**..then you definitely dont need to use **"*"** for checking if the entry in the table exists.

Comment: select 1 and select id ,which is better?Oh i know...... may be it has no difference....because the primary key is unique!

Comment: @Dolphin:- select 1 will still be a better choice as it will only check if there is an entry in database. But when you say select id from table then it would fetch all the id's from the table. So performance wise select 1 would be better :) Hope that makes it clear!